# How to get js file in chrome developer console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

How do I navigate through "../utils/mapPositionUtils" in the chrome developer console. I require the code of the file. Below is another file importing the code.

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = exports.DrawSearchLayer = exports.initialState = void 0;

var _react = _interopRequireWildcard(require("react"));

var _propTypes = _interopRequireDefault(require("prop-types"));

var _reactAutobind = _interopRequireDefault(require("react-autobind"));

var _throttle2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("lodash/throttle"));

var _drawSearchUtils = require("../util/drawSearchUtils");

var _mapPositionUtils = require("../util/mapPositionUtils");
```

The [link to the site](https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/?searchQueryState=%7B%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22West%20Hollywood%20West%2C%20West%20Hollywood%2C%20CA%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-118.39260815612236%2C%22east%22%3A-118.37574242583672%2C%22south%22%3A34.07223233369331%2C%22north%22%3A34.08322666373706%7D%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A16%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22customRegionId%22%3A%223974d624d3X1-CRdov9a5tjplku_tt63d%22%7D).

I'm a beginner at javascript (I develop in python), so excuse me if this is a basic question :).

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: _"How do I navigate through ..."_ Do mean step through the code while debugging? Or do you mean debug the code in general?

Comment: I mean how do I view the file

Comment: If the code is builded in developer mode you can just navigate the file with `ctrl+P` / `cmd+P`. If the file is bundled you will need to access the minified bundle